# How to specify a WCF execution path under IIS 7.0

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis, iis-7

I have my WCF service that uses a third party DLL. this third party DLL is a com register DLL no problem there. But this DLL used an unmanaged, not registrable DLL that has to be in local execution path of the other DLL. The problem is that when my WCF start on IIS it load the third party DLL assembly but the DLL cannot find his DLL as it's not in my application bin folder. I manually putted the other DLL in the bin folder but the execution path is not there. That third party DLL does have methods to expose files in his directory but it doesn't see the file.

I know the problem is that because if i copy paste the method in a console app it run flawlessly but i HAVE to put the DLL's the third party DLL uses into my BIN folder to make it work. Calling the DLL method to see local file clearly shows that it uses my application execution path. I have no problem with having to do that. If i could force the execution path of my Service to always be the same in a place i could know i would simply shove these extra DLL in their and forget about it.

Anyone have an idea how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution is to create a console application. Install it on the server anywhere else than the web service. Hard code the console executable path into the web service and make the web service start the console app process passing the parameters to it then wait for process exit. Once the console app close go read the log file that it created and extract the result. Then simply return to the client the result.